# Infragistics Grid: Set a Value, display a Text

Tags: .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a infragistics ultragird.

I need to set in a cell a custom object value but to display the Text an other one. Then, when I will navigate through this grid, I need to obtain the set object values, but user should see the corresponding text.

Say, I have as value an enumeration, and the user see in the cell its description attribute.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you saying you have a value of set in a field (say a number) but the number represents a "Look-up" value and you would prefer to display the look-up value (a text value) rather than the numeric equivelent?  Yes that can be done.  Let me know if my assumption is correct and you have your answer. :)

Comment: @RLH: No, say, a value is a City instance, but the text to display is, say, the city name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, As I didn't find a way to mix a string and a "object" in the same cell, I ended up to have hidden columns for real values (objects), and visible columns for that object's description.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method for showing a different value in a grid cell to to the actual data value is to attach a ValueList to the column in question with the values/descriptions added to that ValueList.

I'm not too sure if this works with non-primitive types, it may if you have an implementation of Equals on the type of the objects being stored but I can't check this out at the moment to confirm whether it does or not.

Comment: when attaching a value list, a drop-down box appears in the cell when I mouse-over it. I want that my cells be read-only. From the other part, if in a row the column contains heterogenous type of objects, say the column contains animals types, and in the first row we have different kinds of monkeys, and in the second we would select different king of pigs, the single value list for the entire column will not work...

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar things in the past by storing a reference to my object (an instance of `City` in your example) in the cell's `Tag` property and then having a method on the object render that instance into the cell for display.  Sometime's `ToString` is a good candidate for this, sometimes I have a specialized method that produces text more appropriate for display in the grid.